# I am using Decimal format and setting rounding mode to down

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, decimalformat

I am using Decimal format and setting rounding mode to down
While deploying i get the Error as :

```
    cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)
    [javac] location: class java.text.DecimalFormat
    [javac]         df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Can someone help me out here ???

Cheers

Comment: Can we get the code that produces that compile error? We cannot guess it! :)

Comment: @Vakimshaar actually this one is really not hard to guess

Answer (score 1):

You are probably compiling your code with one version of Java that contains the method `setRoundingMode()` introduced in Java 1.6 while deploying your application to a JVM of a Java version prior the introduction of that method (likely Java 1.5).

Comment: Now how do i round for Java 1.5 >

Comment: @Azfar you can always perform the rounding yourself using Math methods or BigDecimal. See more info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_DOWN